# How to Use a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I am trying to create a simple budget application using Java's swing toolkit. The application should ask the user to input a budget item and that item's price in two JTextFields. It will store the information in two ArrayLists, to be later outputted into a text document. Every time the user inputs an item and price (by clicking the "Ok" JButton), two new JTextFields and one new "Ok" JButton is created to store another item and its price.

My problem is that I want the user to be able to input as many budget items that he/she needs. Currently, once the user adds many items, the JTextFields go out of view. I believe that the solution would be to add some sort of scrolling mechanism, but I am having trouble adding a JScrollPane. Does someone with that sort of experience have a solution to this problem?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Budget3 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Double> priceList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private double totalPrice = 0;
    private int okCount = 0;
    private DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("$##,##0.00");
    private JLabel itemTitleLabel;
    private JLabel priceTotal;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Budget3 window = new Budget3();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);  
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Budget3() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100,100,800,800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("BUDGET");
        titleLabel.setBounds(330,16,125,48);
        frame.getContentPane().add(titleLabel);
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 30));

        itemTitleLabel = new JLabel("Item (" + itemList.size() + ")");
        itemTitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        itemTitleLabel.setBounds(49, 117, 151, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(itemTitleLabel);

        JLabel priceTitleLabel = new JLabel("Price");
        priceTitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        priceTitleLabel.setBounds(225, 117, 69, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(priceTitleLabel);

        priceTotal = new JLabel("Total:     " + f.format(totalPrice));
        priceTotal.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        priceTotal.setBounds(450, 117, 274, 37);
        frame.getContentPane().add(priceTotal);

        addItem();

    }

    int textFieldCount = 0;

    public void addItem(){

        int labelY = 180 + okCount*30;  

        JTextField itemField = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(itemField);
        itemField.setBounds(50, labelY, 150, 30);
        itemField.setColumns(10);

        JTextField priceField = new JTextField();
        textFieldCount++;
        frame.getContentPane().add(priceField);
        priceField.setBounds(225, labelY, 150, 30);
        priceField.setColumns(10);

        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                int buttonY = okButton.getY();
                int spotCount = (buttonY - 180) / 30;

                try{
                    itemList.remove(spotCount);
                    priceList.remove(spotCount);
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException bounds){}

                String item = itemField.getText();
                String priceString = priceField.getText();
                double price = Double.parseDouble(priceString);         
                itemList.add(spotCount, item);
                priceList.add(spotCount, price);

                totalPrice = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < priceList.size(); i++){
                    totalPrice = totalPrice + priceList.get(i);
                }
                if(itemList.size() < 2){
                    itemTitleLabel.setText("Item (" + itemList.size() + ")");
                }
                else{
                    itemTitleLabel.setText("Items (" + itemList.size() + ")");
                }
                priceTotal.setText("Total:     " + f.format(totalPrice));

                if(itemList.size() == textFieldCount)
                {
                    okCount++;
                    addItem();
                }

            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(okButton);
        okButton.setBounds(450,labelY,62,30);

        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();

}
```

}

Comment: `JScrollPane`, like containers in Swing is depend on the functionality of the layout manager API. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify. Have a looka at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer -- Thank you for the help. You are definitely right about avoiding the null layout. One of my goals is definitely to learn how to use layout managers. However, for this simple application, the budget item and its price are stored every time a jbutton is pressed. Then, two new fields and one new jbutton is created and placed 30 pixels beneath the previous fields and jbutton. How could this be done with a layout manager without using the setBounds feature?

Comment: Also, the program really needs a jscrollbar because if you store more than 18 or so budget items, the fields and jbuttons go out of the JFrame's view.

Comment: Use a `JTable` or `JList` instead (store manage each item)

Comment: Wow. The JTable would have been perfect for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a JScrollBar with all default properties. Its orientation
// will be vertical, current value 0, extent 10, minimum 0, and maximum
// 100
   JScrollBar sb1 = new JScrollBar();
// Create a horizontal JScrollBar with default values
   JScrollBar sb2 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
// Create a horizontal JScrollBar with a current value of 50,
// extent 15, minimum 1 and maximum 150
   JScrollBar sb3 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 50, 15, 1,150);

// Create a JScrollPane with no component as its viewport and
// with default scrollbars policy as "As Needed"
   JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane();
// Create a JScrollPane with a JTextArea as its viewport and
// with default scrollbars policy as "As Needed"
   JTextArea description = new JTextArea(10, 60);
   JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane(description);
// Create a JScrollPane with a JTextArea as its viewport and
// both scrollbars policy set to "show always"
   JTextArea comments = new JTextArea(10, 60);
   JScrollPane sp3 = new JScrollPane(comments,
   JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
   JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: You don't need to create `JScrollBar`s, you never actually use them anyway